# JSON user search

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/0b6994bb9a8b5a3a3cc5c56111bb3ce7) with a `JSON database` and an `XHR object`.

The `user` parameter from `getUsers(user)` method is an input value.
I want select an user from the `db` via input search value. But i don't know how to set the `http url` or the `searching algorithm`.

I can select an user via: `user.Name1` but how can i modify the entries after the dot `.Name1` so it can be selected with the input value.

E.g: `user. + "input value"`. I can't figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I inderstood you right, you want to access it via square brackets:
`user[userValue]` where `userValue` is your input variable

Answer (score 1):

You can access on object like this `user["Name1"]` and as such can do this : `user[input_value_variable]`